# Camera issue when setting AVCaptureDevice to 1 fps

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have an issue with the AVFoundation framework. Whenever I set the FPS of the camera to 1, after a while, my FaceTime HD camera LED starts blinking with one second intervals. Also, no calls to the delegate (sample buffer delegate) are called anymore.

The issue does not occur when I set it to 2 FPS but for the app that I'm developing I need it to be set to 1 FPS.

Just checking here if anyone else has problems with their camera when setting it to one FPS. If necessary, I'll post a bug report with Apple.
I'm using a Macbook Air from mid 2013, running macOS 10.13.3.

Here's the code that I use to set the FPS:

```
/// Set the frame rate of the current av capture session, if it is supported by the camera.
///
/// - Parameter fps: The desired frames per second.
func set(fps: Int) {

    guard let captureDevice = captureDevice,
        let format = captureDevice.activeFormat else { return }
    let doubleFPS = Double(fps)

    // Lock the device before changing the frame rate.
    try? captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()

    // Look for a supported frame rate range that is supported by the camera.
    for range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as! [AVFrameRateRange] {
        if range.minFrameRate <= doubleFPS &&
            range.maxFrameRate >= doubleFPS {
            let time: CMTime = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: CMTimeScale(fps))
            captureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = time
            captureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = time
            break
        }
    }

    // Unlock the device now that we are done.
    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are processing the frames? If you're doing it with  `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` you can discard any frames you don't want to achieve your desired framerate. If you're recording to a file (e.g. `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`), you can't.

p.s the issue you describe sounds like a bug. Ideally you would log it.

Comment: Yes indeed, I am using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. Could you eleborate on how I could drop frames so that I would only process 1 frame per second? The strategy that I described in my question seems to be the way to go according to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2445/_index.html

Comment: That document is about unintentionally dropping frames. You want to deliberately drop them - right now you’re writing/appending too many frames per second, so examine the sample buffer’s presentation timestamp and if the previous one was less than a second ago, discard/don’t append this new one. Your frame rate may drop below 1 FPS this way, so you might need to combine incoming frames to get your desired 1 FPS

Comment: I've implemented your proposed strategy and it seems to be the best solution for my problem right now. It still doesn't explain the issue I described in my question though.

Comment: The issue you described sounds like a macOS bug. Log it if you have the time.